# import custom module to django settings with string path from same folder

Tags: python, django, module

I have a `permissions.py` file at my core app in django which I want to use its `My_has_permission` class for project level permissions in `settings.py`. note `settings.py` and `permissions.py` are in same folder. so I tried

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        '.permissions.My_has_permission',
    ]
}
```

but it gave this error: `TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for`

so how can I have this package as my `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`?

###### here on Im explaining my tries:

1. I want the opposite of what `importlib.import_module('.a', package='b')` does
2. also make another `ss.py` and with

```
from .permissions import My_has_permission
print(My_has_permission.__file__)
```

tried to get the path but gave error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`, this error is not because `djangorestframework` is not installed. note I say this because I have used some imports from `rest_framework`. besides error is from `from .permissions import My_has_permission` in `ss.py`

so my question is it my `permissions.py` faulty?

```
from rest_framework import permissions

PERMS_MAP = {
    # 'OPTIONS': 'view_',
    'HEAD': 'view_',
    'GET': 'view_',
    'DELETE': 'delete_',
    'PATCH': 'change_',
    'POST': 'add_',
    'PUT': 'change_'
}
class My_has_permission(permissions.BasePermission):
    app_label = view.queryset.model._meta.app_label
    model_name = view.queryset.model._meta.model_name
    return request.user.has_perm(str(self.app_label+'.'+PERMS_MAP[request.method]+self.model_name)) or request.user.is_admin or request.user.is_superuser
```

#### update

I moved `permissions.py` to another app(`users`) and I did

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'users.permissions.My_has_permission',
    ]
}
```

so solved the problem practically but problem with this trail(`from same folder`) remains unsolved.

Comment: I think this will help you to understand about current [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22176915/14457833)

Comment: it seems error in `from .permissions import My_has_permission` should have nothing to do with django